# How many wings do Chayot have

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, number, malach-angel, ezekiel--the-book

In the first chapter of Yechezkel, the Chayot are described ambiguously as having four wings. Is this per side, or a total number?

Comment: How many sides do you suspect they have?

Comment: @DoubleAA, 4 (15 characters)

Comment: Why do you suspect that they'd have wings on their sides and front and back?

Comment: @DoubleAA, this is actually a question from my non-Jewish professor, I posted it here as I figured I would get a better answer than elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Targum on that passuk spells out the numbers and Rashi quotes him. Each chaya has 64 wings. They each have four partzuphim, each partzuph has four faces and each face has four wings. 4 X 4 x 4=64. Then, being that he saw 4 chayos turns out he saw 256 wings.